# unique words in lines of text read from standard input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to see how many unique words there is in standard input.

```
import sys
s = sys.stdin.readlines()
seen = []
for lines in s:
   if lines not in seen:
       seen = seen + (lines.split())
       seen.append(lines)
       print (len(seen))
```

I know I am on right track but if Tree and tree should not be counted as separate unique words.

Also Monday and 1 are words but – is not.

Comment: What all counts as a word?  Characters and digits?

Comment: @zondo "Monday and 1 are words but – is not." I would assume "alphanumerical" is the criteria.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold

Comment: or https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower if your python isn't that fresh

Comment: would u say lower all the input and then check

Answer (score 0):

```
seen = []
for line in s:
    for word in line.strip().split():
        if word.isalnum() and word.lower() not in (x.lower() for x in seen):
            seen.append(word)
print(len(seen))
```

Or better (if you want only the length, but not the words themselves):

```
print(len(set(word.lower() for line in s for word in line.strip().split() if word.isalnum()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this code snippet can help you in few lines. Basicly the idea is to use set.

```
st = set([])
for lines in s.split('\n'):
    print(lines)
    st=set(lines.split()).union(st)
print(st)
```